# при запуске приложения пишет Waiting for debuging

Tags: android-studio

Не пойму что я сделал, но теперь приложение, которое я разработываю, не могу запустить без отладки. если выполнить опцию run в android studio, то на телефоне появиться сообщение waiting for debugging и можно только закрыть. работает только если запустить в режиме отладки. но почему так? как исправить?

Comment: вообще насколько я знаю, нужно подключить телефон с отладкой к пк, и тогда студия сможет его распознать нормально, может вы не run нажимаете а debug? добавьте немного больше подробностей

Comment: @Andrew я run нажимал. потом долгое время не запускал и эта проблема изчезла сама собой.